# studio-controls 2.1.4 vs 2.1.64

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-studio, midi, backport

Does anyone have a copy of the studio-controls 2.1.4 .deb for 20.04 from the backports-ppa?  The minute I ran updates and studio-controls 2.1.64 hit my machine, my audio and MIDI setup fell apart. Studio-controls and qjackctl no longer agreed on the state of jackd, audio connections that had automatically restored whenever I logged back on went away, and studio-controls could no longer reliably start or stop jackd. In addition, no matter what set of MIDI related options I tried, the system no longer recognized any of my MIDI hardware under "a2j" in the MIDI tab on qjackctl. All of my soft synths or plugins under Carla would only show up under the MIDI tab, never under the ALSA tab, so there was no way to connect the keyboard or control surface to any of them. I finally ended up burning down and reinstalling 20.04 without the backports-ppa, which fixed all the jack-related issues, but that left me with a backlevel Carla that doesn't do VST3 support.  So, anyone still hanging onto a 2.1.4 .deb that I could install?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy studio-controls`?

Comment: At the moment I'm running on the reinstall without the backports ppa so studio-controls doesn't show.  I rely on this machine for work, so it's going to be a bit before I can monkey with it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t specifically for 20.04, but it looks like you can [get the package from pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/studio-controls):

[image: Screen Capture]

You may need to do a little bit of dependency wrangling to get everything “just right”.

Comment: Why not use https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/studio-controls ?

Answer (score 0):

I exchanged a few messages with developer Erich Eickmeyer. He was rather surprised I'd wound up with 2.1.64, which is beta, when I didn't have the studio-controls staging PPA included in my repository list. Apparently a beta build went sideways and the 2.1.64 beta wound up in the backports PPA. He fixed the PPA, I re-added it to my repository list, and after an update/upgrade everything was working right again with studio-controls 2.1.4, Ardour 6, and Carla 2.3.